# Use CSS to select range of elements in Python

Tags: python, css

I have a table with 28 rows.  I'm trying to select only the 25 rows with data, skipping the first header row and the last two footer rows.  The following selector works in Firefox's Web Console but in Python, returns 0 rows.

```
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
sel = CSSSelector('table tr:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+26)')
```

How should I select a range of elements?

Comment: Well you could still select all and then remove those you do not need, right?

Comment: Are you sure, that `nth-child` selectors are supported by `lxml.cssselect`?

Comment: @kecer I'd prefer to do it in a CSS selector if possible
@Alik Yes, `'table tr:nth-child(n+2)'` works, but chaining another `nth-child` doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the nth-child range is not implemented in lxml.cssselect.
Instead, you can use the beautiful slicing syntax of Python:

```
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
from lxml.etree import fromstring
# Document with table, containing header, three data rows and two footer rows:
doc = fromstring('''<table><tr><td>header</td></tr><tr><td>Data 1</td></tr><tr><td>Data 2</td></tr><tr><td>Data 3</td></tr><tr><td>footer1</td></tr><tr><td>footer2</td></tr></table>''')
sel = CSSSelector('table tr')
rows = sel(doc)[1:-2] # remove header, footer1, footer2 from result
for tr in rows:
    print tr.getchildren()[0].text
```

Output is:

```
Data 1
Data 2
Data 3
```